# Connect Android Device with phpMyadmin

Tags: android, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem with my project, that I hope you guys can help me fix.

I am following the instructions from [this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) to create a connection from an Android app to mysql with phpmyadmin.
If I use Virtual Machine to test with link of file php is:

```
 private static String url_all_products = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/get_all_products.php";
```

This worked!

Now I want to run it from my real android device, so I change from 10.0.2.2 to my 192.168.0.104 (this is my new IP) but it does not work.

My log show this:

```
****05-24 15:56:16.130: E/JSON Parser(2272): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject****
```

This is my code:

```
 private static String url_all_products = "http://192.168.0.104/android_connect/get_all_products.php";
```

If I set it to 10.0.2.2 on Virtual Machine it works!